# JSON GET returns HTML when called from code/console but returns JSON object when called from web address

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to run this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://foodfetch.us/OrderApi/locations',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //do work here
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, the AJAX call returns HTML source code, not the JSON object that it should be returning. If you copy the URL into any web browser, the JSON object shows up in plain text.

Can anyone explain what silly thing am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because that url leads to a page with an embeded frame, the frame url leads to the actual JSON data

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Evans has pointed out in the comments, the URL in the code links to a page with an embedded frame, I was able to get the code working by using the URL that the frame links to.